# NET CORE 2.0 - Ubuntu 14.04 - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu-14.04

When I run dotnet xxx.DLL in Ubuntu 14.04 x64 the following problem occurs:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(String[] args)
   at Teste.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args).
```

Follow some configurations of my project:

**Project.csproj**

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;ubuntu.14.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

I tried to place the missing package in Nuget and the same thing did not work.

Linux server owns NET CORE 2.

I checked if the DLL was on the server (and it was).

Does anyone have a suggestion?

I have added more details to them at https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/902